# Unable to modify the elements of dict in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have defined a function called `modify` which modifies given string. I have a dict called `elements` which have some strings stored in them. However, I am unable to modify those strings stored in the dict.

```
x = "abc"
x = modify(x)
```

This works but when I do;

```
for element in elements:
    element = modify(element)
```

This does not work. Any idea why? I'm fairly new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify the elements of a dict whilst iterating through them.

You'd need to use something like this:

```
for key in elements:
    elements[key] = modify(elements[key])
```

Comment: @JohnSmith: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.

Comment: There is a time limit for accepting the answer. My rep does not allow me to upvote.

I tried clicking on answer. But it asked me to wait for x minutes and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to apply a function to each member of a dictionary, consider using a dict comprehension:

```
elements = {k: modify(v) for k, v in elements.items()}
```

If you are using python 2.7 use `elements.iteritems()` instead of `elements.items()`.

Comment: This is a bit complex for me. As I am just a beginner. I will go with Satya's answer. Thanks anyways.